# How to create arrays with different number of columns using a loop in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, prawn

I need to create arrays with different numbers of columns depending on whether certain variable values are "Show" or "Hide".

- `activity_types` has many `activities`
- `activity_type` belongs to a user
- `activities` will have a number of `columns: date, duration, cost, subject...`
- `activity_types` has a corresponding toggle column for each activity column,
    for example: `subject_toggle`, `duration_toggle

these toggle columns can have values of only "Show" or "Hide"

So I want to create a series of tables in **prawnpdf** for all the different activity_types. Each table should have different sets of columns shown depending on whether the `activity_type` toggle variable for that column is "show" or "hide"

I began working on this and quickly did not know how it conditionally creates columns in the array. I could leave it blank (have an if statement that would output blank if its "Hide") but it wouldn't remove the column.

Below is my code to create the tables for **prawnpdf**.

```
ActivityType.all.each do |type|
define_method("method_#{type.id}") do
  move_down 20
  font "Nunito"
  text type.title, :align => :left, size: 13, style: :bold
  move_down 5
  table eval("rows_#{type.id}"), :position => :center, :width => 540, :column_widths => {0 => 50, 8 => 60},
                                 :cell_style => {:font => "Nunito", :size => 10} do
    row(0).font_style = :bold
    columns(0..8).align = :center
    self.row_colors = ["F0F0F0", "FFFFFF"]
    self.header = true
  end
end end


  ActivityType.all.each do |type|
define_method("rows_#{type.id}") do
  [["Date", "Subject", "Details", "Time (min)","Contact","Detail","Outcome","Agent",""]] +
    type.activities.order(date: :asc).map do |activity|
      [activity.date.strftime("%b %d"), activity.subject, activity.contact, activity.detail,
      activity.outcome, activity.agent, activity.customer, activity.cost, activity.duration.to_i ]
    end
end end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array#compact` to remove the empty elements from your array:

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-compact

> **compact → new_ary**
>
> Returns a copy of self with all nil elements removed.

```
[ "a", nil, "b", nil, "c", nil ].compact
                  #=> [ "a", "b", "c" ]
```

However, it would only remove `nil` values. If your values can also be empty strings, you could use `reject`.

In your particular case it would be:

```
[activity.date.strftime("%b %d"), activity.subject, activity.contact, activity.detail,activity.outcome, activity.agent, activity.customer, activity.cost, activity.duration.to_i ].reject { |el| el.nil? || el.empty? }
```